# Raphael end of line follows cursor

Tags: javascript, raphael

Note: this question is similar to a few others, but I've had trouble extracting the central logic from the answers.

I'm trying to do the following: a user can click the page, anchoring one end of a line. Eventually, she will click again to anchor the other end. In the meantime, though the second line end should float with the cursor, thereby showing what the final line would like at any point.

I believe the solution will involve mousemove(), but I haven't been able to find a simple example showing how this works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I did it myself (the user was drawing polygon by hand):

- The points (your ends of line) were made with `Paper.circle()`
- Handling the jQuery click events with `$.click()`, I was able to draw my points
- Once you have your first point, draw a line with `Paper.path()` between your last point and the cursor position
- Then you want to refresh the path inside your `$.mousemove()` handler

Here is how I advice you to *refresh* the path object (we don't want to create a new one each time right ?):

```js
var sNewPath = 'M10,20L30,40';
var oPath.attr({ 'path':sNewPath });
```